# boundary of $\mathbb{Q}^n$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: general-topology

what is the boundary of $\mathbb{Q}^n$ as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, endowed with the standard topology? I would say, it is $\partial \mathbb{Q}^n=\emptyset$ because $\mathbb{Q}^n$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Is it correct?

sorry, I mean, $\operatorname{int} \mathbb{Q}^n=\emptyset$, that was a mistake ...

Answer (score 4):

The boundary of a set $A$ is defined as
$$\partial A=\overline A\cap \overline{\complement A}$$

Since $\Bbb Q^n$ and its complement are both dense in $\Bbb R^n$, the boundary is the whole space.